# Selecting Categories to display products using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi is there a tutorial or some sort of resource that can help me work out how to actually select products from a database based on the category i selected, mind you the category is not just 1 tier, it will consist of a 3 tier category navigation.

meaning it should only load the page for a list of products that i have selected if i click on the third tier in that particular category, not the first or second tier, all i have the first and second tier doing is displaying a list of the child categories in that tier.

I have my categories sorted by using parent_id's in a database and i list them using PHP, i just don't know how i would go about selecting the products for a particular category, and i was wondering if i could get some resources that could assist me or help with the database side using MySQL and PHP side of things. thanks.

Comment: I think you need to separate your thinking about what you will do with mysql (which would be something like `select * from products where category = 'sneakers'`) versus what you would do with PHP (which would be rendering your catalog nav pages so that all but your childless categories point to category drill-down (which would display the result of `select * from cats where parent=?`) and only the chidless pages point to the product listing view.)

Comment: Okay i see what you mean, you have made it a bit clearer for me now